# VPN addresses match internal network addresses

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, routing

I've setup a VPN for my work network, my home network is 192.168.1.0/24 range, but so is part of the work network that I want to access.

I need to be able to remote to my computer at 192.168.1.136.  Is there a way I can force my Mac to go via that route?

Here's my existing routing table:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc          185        0     en0       
default            link#16            UCSI            0        0  ipsec0       
10.1/16            172.16.241.4       UGSc            1        3  ipsec0       
51.141.102.26      192.168.1.1        UGHS            0        0     en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              2    22656     lo0       
169.254            link#9             UCS             1        0     en0      !
172.16.220.8/32    127.0.0.1          UGSc            0        0     lo0       
172.16.241/24      172.16.241.4       UGSc            0        0  ipsec0       
172.16.241.4       172.16.241.4       UH              4        0  ipsec0       
192.168.0/16       172.16.241.4       UGSc            0        0  ipsec0       
192.168.1          link#9             UCS             7        0     en0      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#9             UCS             1        0     en0      !
192.168.1.1        10:da:43:b3:59:ad  UHLWIir        44      674     en0   1150
192.168.1.4        b8:27:eb:c1:70:25  UHLWIi          2        9     en0   1159
192.168.1.12       d4:a3:3d:67:87:73  UHLWIi          1      152     en0   1088
192.168.1.13       d4:90:9c:dd:da:b0  UHLWIi          1      169     en0    854
192.168.1.14       d4:a3:3d:62:8c:80  UHLWIi          1      154     en0   1049
192.168.1.18/32    link#9             UCS             0        0     en0      !
192.168.1.51       38:53:9c:83:f4:1e  UHLWI           0       44     en0     13
192.168.1.52       38:53:9c:83:3b:bb  UHLWIi          3      170     en0    960
192.168.1.59       dc:56:e7:45:db:ab  UHLWIi          1      120     en0    722
192.168.245.1      172.16.241.4       UGHS            0        0  ipsec0       
224.0.0/4          link#9             UmCS            1        0     en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#16            UmCSI           0        0  ipsec0       
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#9             UCS             0        0     en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#16            UCSI            0        0  ipsec0
```

Comment: I don't think there's a non-horrible way to do this. Can you reconfigure your home router to use a different private IP range (and then probably reboot everything on the private network)?

Comment: I second Gordon. Subnets are supposed to be unique. Use a different subnet at home or get your work to use a different private subnet, as this is probably going to cause problems for everyone as 192.168.1.0/24 is a very common default subnet for home NAT gateways.

Comment: "Part" of the work network? So do you get a 192.168.1.0/24 address as the IP or default gateway of the tunnel? If not it shouldn't be a problem AFAIK (just that you won't get to access your "physical" LAN when you are connected to the VPN).